# Does the Ubuntu Linux 16.04 daemon function execute a double fork?

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, fork

Does the Ubuntu Linux 16.04 daemon function execute a double fork? If so, why is a double fork necessary?

[EDIT May 30 2016 8:11 AM] This is the official Linux Foundation source code for the daemon function  I am referring to in this question.

```
92 int daemon(int nochdir, int noclose) 
93 { 
94     int status = 0; 
95 
96     openlog("daemonize", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON); 
97 

98     /* Fork once to go into the background. */ 
99     if((status = do_fork()) < 0 ) 
100         ; 
101 

102     /* Create new session */ 
103     else if(setsid() < 0)               /* shouldn't fail */ 
104         status = -1; 
105 

106     /* Fork again to ensure that daemon never reacquires a control terminal. */ 
107     else if((status = do_fork()) < 0 ) 
108         ; 
109 

110     else 
111     { 
112         /* clear any inherited umask(2) value */ 
113 

114         umask(0); 
115 

116         /* We're there. */ 
117 

118         if(! nochdir) 
119         { 
120             /* Go to a neutral corner. */ 
121             chdir("/"); 
122         } 
123 

124         if(! noclose) 
125             redirect_fds(); 
126     } 
127 

128     return status; 
129 }
```

Depending on the path of execution it will either fork one or twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We appear to be referencing the `daemon(3)` library call, source code for which may be at #1 https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/daemon.c or at #2 https://github.com/bmc/daemonize/blob/master/daemon.c. Both versions are documented in this single [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html).

The source code for #1 shows a single `fork(2)`. The source code for #2 shows a double `fork(2)`. Superficially both functions appear to deliver the same result but by different means.

Seeing as a double `fork(2)` is not always necessary I suppose this counters the thrust of the second part of your question and renders it no longer necessary. However, the underlying reason for this approach was to guarantee that the forked process could not under any circumstances reacquire a controlling terminal. The newer code solves this problem by setting the child to be a new session leader.

There are other related questions on this and other StackOverflow sites that ask similar questions. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881388/what-is-the-reason-for-performing-a-double-fork-when-creating-a-daemon).

Answer (score 2):

The `glibc`'s `daemon()` function only does a single fork as can be seen in [its source code](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/misc/daemon.c).

What you were looking at initially is in the kernel's source code and not referenced from the outside directly.

The use of a double-fork depends on the implementation used to actually call the daemon program and is not needed on most designs since the daemons are not started from a regular session.

Forking twice like you saw in the kernel's source code will completely detach the process from its parent since the parent is inherited in the first `fork()`.  Calling the second `fork()` and terminating the parent makes the process get assigned `1` as its `PPID` (parent process ID), which also completely removes any assigned TTYs.

Comment: I just accepted your answer after doing Stack Exchange with you through the night the last 20 hours. Thank you.

Comment: The other answer was indeed quite good.

Comment: +1 for all your effort on this too. I hadn't realised the original (now wiped) code was from the kernel.